# MySQL: Return all results where all conditions (but no other) are true

Tags: sql, mysql

There are two tables:

```
Packages

id     name
1      red
2      blue
3      yellow

Contents

packageid      item           size
1              square         A
1              circle         B
1              triangle       C
2              square         A
2              circle         B
3              square         A
```

If we query for `{ item:square, size:A }` we only want `{ packages.id:3 }`

If we query for `{ item:square, size:A }` and `{ item:circle, size:B }` we only want `{ packages.id:2 }`

If we query for `{ item:square, size:A }` and `{ item:circle, size:B }` and `{ item:triangle, size:C }` we only want `{ packages.id:1 }`

If there is more than one package that matches exactly, we would like all of them.

This seems to work, but it's not terribly elegant:

```
SELECT 
p.id,
p.name,
c.item,
c.size

FROM Packages p
LEFT JOIN Contents c ON (
  c.packageid=p.id
)

WHERE (
    ( p.id IN ( SELECT packageid FROM Contents WHERE item='square' AND size='A' ) 
    AND 
    ( p.id IN ( SELECT packageid FROM Contents WHERE item='circle' AND size='B' ) 
)
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contents WHERE packageid=p.id ) = 2;
```

Comment: Do you understand what `AND` means?  How could `( c.item='square' AND c.size='A') AND   ( c.item='circle' AND c.size='B')` ever be `true`?

Comment: yea, those wouldn't ever both be true. that's what my question is about. i considered not putting in a query effort, but had a feeling there would be criticism for that, too.

Comment: Should circle+b return anything?

Comment: no to just { item:circle, size:B }, since there's no Package that matches exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXISTS`, you will get your wanted results

Exist  is the fastest way to check if values with the wanted values are there.

an INDEX on poacage_id, item and size will increase the perfomace

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.name, c.item, c.size
FROM
    Packages p
        LEFT JOIN
    Contents c ON (c.packageid = p.id)
WHERE

(SELECT 
        1
   FROM
        Contents
    WHERE
        packageid = p.id AND (item = 'square' AND size = 'A'))
AND (SELECT 
        1
   FROM
        Contents
    WHERE
        packageid = p.id AND (item = 'circle' AND size = 'B')) 
  AND  (SELECT 
        1
   FROM
        Contents
    WHERE
        packageid = p.id AND (item = 'triangle' AND size = 'C')) 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contents WHERE packageid = p.id) = 3;
```

| id | name | item | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | triangle | C |
| 1 | red | circle | B |
| 1 | red | square | A |

```
SELECT
p.id, p.name, c.item, c.size
FROM
    Packages p
        LEFT JOIN
    Contents c ON (c.packageid = p.id)
WHERE

(SELECT 
        1
   FROM
        Contents
    WHERE
        packageid = p.id AND (item = 'square' AND size = 'A'))
AND (SELECT 
        1
   FROM
        Contents
    WHERE
        packageid = p.id AND (item = 'circle' AND size = 'B')) 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contents WHERE packageid = p.id) = 2;
```

| id | name | item | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | blue | circle | B |
| 2 | blue | square | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J1ZeCAsj)

Comment: Both of these seem to be valid solutions (yours, @nbk and below, @SelVazi)! Brilliant, both! So how do I know which to mark as Accepted answer? Note to self: it's going to take me some reading to understand SelVazi's solution which will introduce me to some MySQL 8+ syntax. But I guess that's my homework for this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

The main condition is getting a package that precisely matches the number of rows based on the given conditions. For example, if two sets of conditions are passed, we should receive Package 2, which contains two rows :

```
with filter as (
  select 'square' item, 'A' size union all
  select 'circle', 'B'
),
filter_with_count as (
  select *, count(*) over() as cnt
  from filter
),
cte as (
  select p.id, p.name, c.item, c.size,
         count(p.id) over(partition by p.id) as cnt
  from Packages p
  inner join Contents c on c.packageid = p.id
)
select c.id, c.name, c.item, c.size
from cte c
inner join filter_with_count f 
           on c.item = f.item 
           and c.size = f.size
           and c.cnt = f.cnt;
```

Explanations :

The condition(s) will be passed as a dataset on the first CTE.

The second CTE count the rows using the window function `COUNT()`.

The third CTE was used to combine the two tables and count total rows per package.

Finally, in order to obtain the desired result, we must join our filter rows with the combined data by item, size, and count.

Which for this condition

```
('square', 'A') and ('circle', 'B')
```

Results :

```
id  name    item    size
2   blue    square  A
2   blue    circle  B
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iemhm1xd)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` with a string containing the sorted list of required items:

```
select packageid
from contents
group by packageid
having group_concat(concat(item, '|', size) order by item, size separator ',') = 
  'circle|B,square|A';
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/IUBFzsHZ

Comment: Almost the best answer, but It has a limit ! the passing data should be ordered alphabetically, if we pass `square|A,circle|B` instead of `circle|B,square|A` we get no data https://dbfiddle.uk/d3hKrcva

Comment: @SelVazi: Yes, this is what I tried to express with "the sorted list". Maybe I should have been more explicit. Thanks for stressing this in your comment.

Comment: Any consensus on which answer to mark as Accepted?